# Dictionary-Sorting in bigger projects

Tags: c#, wpf

My concern is how to handle ResourceDictionarys in a WPF (MVVM)-Project. I usually only create small Projects, so it doesn't matter that much, but since I created a Project-Template to handle some of the boilerplating, I'm really interested into this Topic.

I found the following approach on Stack Overflow: [“Resource Dictionary (WPF)” naming convention and managing suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021844/resource-dictionary-wpf-naming-convention-and-managing-suggestions)

The User suggests the following Dictionaries:

- Fonts and Font-Sizes (Fonts.xaml)
- Brushes and Colors (Brushes.xaml)
- Generic Control Styles, without keys (CoreStyles.xaml)
- Data Templates and TemplateSelectors (DataTemplates.xaml)
- Converters (Converters.xaml)
- BitmapImages for use as Image sources (Icons.xaml)
- Specific, keyed styles (Styles.xaml)

I created them and just loaded them all on the App_Start, but now it gets dicy: Since I'd like to define my assignments as StaticResource (for performance reasons, from what I read), I need to load them in the exact correct order, as described here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3bea80f9-d1db-4cb7-ae7a-77a02eaf4ec9/resourcedictionary-load-order?forum=wpf.

This causes some "Egg-Chicken"-problems for me, since in the Styles.Xaml, I have stuff like:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="StyleButtonNavigation" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,10" />
</Style>
```

So, I'd have to load CoreStyles before Styles, but CoreStyles then uses other stuff as well etc, and that's just the simplest of a possible application.

Another approach I found was to create a ResourceDictionary for each Style etc.: https://projekt202.com/blog/2010/xaml-organization/ 
This seems to be the approach, which corresponds most to the SRP, but I'm not seeing this scaling well into a larger project.

Interesting enough, I didn't find any guidelines or best practices from Microsoft about this topic.